# Migrating VB6 database to windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vb6-migration, dataprovider

Firstly I just want to point out that I know literally next to nothing about VB6. I'm trying to help out a friend by moving all her stuff from her old XP machine to her new windows 8 machine. I've got almost everything except her VB6 database. Can anyone help me out please?

I've copied over the VB6 folder containing the database. When I run it I get the below error.

"Run-time error 3706 - Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

I've had a look around on google and found the file that contains the provider details. Does anyone know what I need to change to make it work?

Your help is greatly receveid!

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Startup"
Option Explicit

Public Gdb As ADODB.Connection
Public GfrmMainForm As frmMain
Public GstrPrinterFont As String

Sub Main()

Dim strFullName As String

    Set GfrmMainForm = New frmMain
    GfrmMainForm.Show

    strFullName = ZADFullDatabaseName("Contacts", "M")
    If Not ZIsFile(strFullName) Then
        MsgBox strFullName & " does not exist", vbOKOnly
        MsgBox ("Terminating " & App.Title)
        End                         ' Something wrong with files, so exit
    End If

    Set Gdb = New ADODB.Connection
    Gdb.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Gdb.IsolationLevel = adXactCursorStability
    Gdb.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Data Source=" _
        & strFullName & ";"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the installed  OLE DB Provider for Jet,
Change:

```
Gdb.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Data Source=" &  strFullName & ";"
```

to

```
Gdb.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" &  strFullName & ";"
```

or

```
Gdb.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &  strFullName & ";"
```